# How to avoid the assigned value being re-written?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The assignment happens appropriately for each category, but if the blocks get full and there are IDs pending in the category and we assign them to a new block, the old assignments get rewritten. Also how do I print the whole new dataframe at the end, because when I am trying it only shows the D block assignment...

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("database.csv")

blocks = {"A": 5, "B": 30, "C": 50, "D": 100}
for key, value in blocks.items():
    print("For block " + key + " capacity is " + str(value))
    while True:
        s = input("Which category to be allocated? ")
        dataFrame = data[data['Category'].str.contains(s)]
        if not dataFrame.empty:
            dataFrame['Block'] = key

            # for loop for Sr. Number
            spc = blocks[key]
            i = 1
            for index, row in dataFrame.iterrows():
                if i > spc:
                    break
                dataFrame.loc[index, 'Sr.'] = str(i)
                i += 1
            print(dataFrame)
            break

print(dataFrame)


This is the input 
Name,ID,Category 
ABC,2020,G 
WER,2021,M 
XCV,2022,T 
GFV,2034,M 
WEQ,2021,M 
WEW,2021,M 
WET,2021,M 
WEY,2021,M 
WLK,2021,M 
WYH,2021,M 

expected output 
Name,ID,Category,Block, Sr. 
1 WER 2021 M A 1 
3 GFV 2034 M A 2 
4 WEQ 2021 M A 3 
5 WEW 2021 M A 4 
6 WET 2021 M A 5 

7 WEY 2021 M B 1
8 WLK 2021 M B 2
9 WYH 2021 M B 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, filter out the non-M categories with `loc`, then assign the blocks of the groups in order and use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) per group of blocks to enumerate them:

```
s = pd.Series(blocks)
m = df['Category'].eq('M')

(df
 .loc[m]
 .assign(**{'block': s.index.repeat(s)[:m.sum()],
            'Sr.': lambda d: d.groupby('block')
                              .cumcount().add(1)
           })
)
```

output:

```
  Name    ID Category block  Sr.
1  WER  2021        M     A    1
3  GFV  2034        M     A    2
4  WEQ  2021        M     A    3
5  WEW  2021        M     A    4
6  WET  2021        M     A    5
7  WEY  2021        M     B    1
8  WLK  2021        M     B    2
9  WYH  2021        M     B    3
```

Comment: What is the logic behind groupby and cumcount

Comment: I'm confused as to where this should be included because if it goes into the for loop for Sr., it's not solving the problem...

Comment: @AdamBurri I added more details. `cumcount` is to enumerate the blocks per group. There is not need for a loop the code is self-sufficient. You just need `data` and `block` as "input".

Comment: currently the code can only work for category M...?

Comment: It can work for other values if you change `m = df['Category'].eq('M')`. If you need to generalize, please open a new question with a clear example